# Android project creates 2 icons on menu

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I have an Android social sharing application with FB sharing . When i install the application it creates 2 icons with the same name and image . 
1. First Icon open's the main application
2. Second Icon Open's the FB login page .

I am doubting my manifest.xml.But i am not sure what is wrong here .

Adding .xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naval.mailer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/socialicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider860551367360117"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainActivity and LoginActivity both have category launcher so it is creating two icons. Remove category launcher from LoginActivity. This is correct manifest.

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/socialicon"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
>     <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
>         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
>     >
>
>     </activity>
>
>
>
>     <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
>         android:configChanges=
>             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
>         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" />
>
>     <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider860551367360117"
>         android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
>         android:exported="true" />
>
>
> </application>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> </manifest>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have two activities with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The category ***android.intent.category.LAUNCHER*** create a launcher, so,  two icons appear. If you remove one of this, only one icon will appear.